# Wordpress gutenberg editor doesn't display the post custom field

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields, wordpress-gutenberg

I am trying to get `gutenberg block editor` to show the `post custom field`, but it doesn't work!!!

When I go to `options (3 little dots on the upper right corner of screen) > preferences > custom field option` it asks me to reload the page and then after the page reloads, nothing happens, no custom field shows up and in the preferences it's still unchecked!!!

Tried to find some documentation on this issue, no luck so far!!!

[image]

Does anybody know why?
Is this a glitch in the new version of wordpress and gutenberg block editor?

Comment: I'm getting the same problem.

Comment: Can you try this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-fields-gutenberg/? I've installed it and also checked the 'Force Display' field here /wp-admin/options-general.php?page=g7g-cfg

This does then render the default WordPress meta fields but not the ACF ones (for me at least). Weirdly it also adds 'Custom Fields' to the 'Additional panels' region (as per your screenshot) which is slightly different than the 'Custom fields' (lowercase 'f').

I'm interested to see if you get the same result as me.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, I appreciate it. Yea, same thing on my side. I'm on a tight schedule so I had to put something together, so I decided to use "ACF" for my project. This functionality is part of the wordpress core, it ships with wordpress, it should work. I think there is a bug in the gutenberg block editor. I should go and submit an issue on the github for wordpress developers to fix when I get a chance. Thanks anyway, appreciate it.

Comment: So I've just tried turning off all plugins. The 'Custom fields' checkbox behaves as expected if ACF is turned off... so the problem is something to do with ACF.

Comment: OK it turns out that my Field Group configuration was wrong and I can now see my ACF fields on the post edit page. However the 'Custom fields' checkbox is still misbehaving when ACF is turned on. That plugin I mentioned above does help render the standard meta.

Comment: That's right! Exactly!!! It has something to do with ACF plugin. When i got ACF deactivated, the default custom fields were back to normal and behaved as they should!!!! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference:

`ACF plugin` is causing this behavior, so when I got it deactivated, wordpress native `custom fields` appeared.

<s>So I decided to use `ACF` instead of native `custom fields`. I hope this helps anyone who runs into this and clears up some confusion!</s>

## Solution

We could use the following solution to bring back wordpress native `custom fields`:

```php
add_filter("acf/settings/remove_wp_meta_box", '__return_false', 999);
```

Use this `flter hook` in your `functions.php` file of your active theme.

Tested and works seamlessly! ;-)

---

### Explanations

When you activate `ACF plugin`, it decides to hide wordpress native `custom fields`! Super odd!

So here's what happens when you activate `ACF plugin`:

1- It first sets an option `'remove_wp_meta_box'=> true` from its `acf.php` file.
2- Then, it tries to hide/unset the wordpress native `custom fields` from its `field_group_options.php` file, like this:

```php
if ( acf_get_setting( 'remove_wp_meta_box' ) ) {
    unset( $choices['custom_fields'] );
}
```

3- It also has a `filter hook` when using `acf_get_setting` function in its `api-helpers.php` file.

```php
apply_filters( "acf/settings/{$name}", $value );
```

We could take advantage of this `filter hook` to bring back the wordpress native `custom fields`, like this:

```php
add_filter("acf/settings/remove_wp_meta_box", '__return_false', 999);
```